# pyodbc not updating table

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I query a table then loop through it to Update another table.
The console Prints shows correct data.

Not sure how to debug the `cursor.execute` for the UPDATE query.

It is not updating on the table. It's not a permission issue. If I run update command on my SQL workbench it works fine.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("Select Account_Name FROM dsf_CS_WebAppView")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
try:
    cursor.execute("Select fullpath FROM customerdesignmap WHERE 
fullpath LIKE '%{}%'".format(row.Account_Name))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print(len(cursor.fetchall()))
    if len(rows) > 0:
        for rowb in rows:
            print(rowb.fullpath)
            print(row.Account_Name)
            if len(row.Account_Name) > 2:
                cursor.execute("UPDATE customerdesignmap SET householdname = {}, msid = {} WHERE fullpath LIKE '{}'".format(row.Account_Name, row.UniqueProjectNumber, rowb.fullpath))
                conn.commit()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: What is the SQL that is generated? Can you execute it as a standalone query? I would start there.

Comment: @Rayen - With `pass` in your `except` block you are silently discarding any errors that your update statement might throw. My guess is that the dynamic SQL you are generating has invalid syntax, possibly due to string values that aren't quoted. You should be using query parameters anyway, e.g., `... SET householdname = ?, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a pure SQL solution as SQL Server supports `UPDATE` and `JOIN` across multiple tables. This avoids the nested loops, cursor calls, and string formatting of SQL commands.

```sql
UPDATE m
SET m.householdname = v.Account_Name, 
    m.msid = v.UniqueProjectNumber
FROM customerdesignmap m
JOIN dsf_CS_WebAppView v 
  ON m.fullpath LIKE CONCAT('%', v.Account_Name, '%')
```

In Python, run above in a single `cursor.execute()` with `commit()` call.

```py
cursor.execute('''my SQL Query''')
conn.commit()
```